# Jumping without a parachute -- how much horizontal velocity can you achieve?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity, projectile, drag, free-fall

I am curious about the old chestnut of falling from an extreme height -- perhaps 1,000 meters or more -- and whether it is possible to convert most of the vertical velocity to horizontal, or any significant portion.

I realize that if you model wing loading that a human can't fly or glide very efficiently -- and it takes a wingsuit to really do that. But, absent a wing suit, and knowing that skydivers can sometimes travel a few miles in any direction, and that straight-down terminal velocity is on the order of 125 mph (or about 55 m/s)...

1. How much horizontal velocity could one achieve?
2. The amount of horizontal velocity ordinarily would not affect the vertical acceleration (in a vacuum) but we are not in a vacuum, we are in a situation where the downward velocity tops out. Even so it seems to me that people thinking to build up a lot of horizontal v to increase survivability of such a fall are wrong; whatever horizontal v you build up you're still hitting the ground at speed and that vertical vector is the one you want to worry about.

But I am curious if my intuition about the physics here is correct; that no matter what you do in the x- direction, as it were, the z-direction is the one you need to be concerned with.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_(skydiving)

Comment: I'm recalling, from my reading of WWI accounts of aircraft, that a person can achieve a 1:1 or better horizontal vs vertical velocity if they position their body correctly.  Prior to parachutes, pilots would sometimes manage to save themselves by jumping from a burning plane and "gliding" into the nearest body of water.